# How do I shorten (or hide) package names in JUnit?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

I have long package names in JUnit and that makes it difficult to see what tests are being ran. Using Eclipse's "Abbreviate package names" doesn't work, unfortunately. Is there any way of hiding or, preferably, shortening them?

Comment: Difficult to see in what context?

Comment: The JUnit window is not wide enough so I have to scroll along to check which set of tests are being ran. Does that make sense or am I not explaining myself well?

Comment: You can write your own listener (inherited from `org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener`) and make it output whatever short names are pleasing you.  It's not difficult to do but probably still not what you want.

Comment: Move the JUnit view somewhere else, where it can be larger.

Comment: @JBNizet That would still make the class names difficult to see because of the wall of text created by the package names.