# Get rid of showing long package names in JUnit window

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

Is there a way to **shorten, or remove package names** from JUnit test runner window in Eclipse? It is inconvenient that Class name is overflow from the window. Duplicated information is showed, but important isn't.

[image: eclipse junit runner window]

Comment: [Similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320540/how-do-i-shorten-or-hide-package-names-in-junit). Apparently, no one knows. But I would love to know the answer to this too.

Comment: I'm not an Eclipse user, but I keep package names for JUnits as short as possible (eg. test). JUnits normally won't be distributed or makes part of the projects API.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the *Layout* of the results shown in the eclipse plugin

[image]

This removes the hierarchy (the packages) from the results tab and displays the names of test methods

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is partial solution because I lose the grouping in the view